# A complicated boundary value problem leading to third order Eigen sytem [Help in continuing forward] [EDITED]

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, eigenvalues, heat-equation

I have the following elliptic PDE (describing temperature in a plate, *w* in thermal contact with two fluids *h* and *c*):
$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} - (\beta_h+V\beta_c)\theta_w+(\beta_h\theta_h+V\beta_c\theta_c) = 0 \tag 1$$

```
pde = Subscript[λ, h] D[θ[x, y], x, x] + Subscript[λ, c] V D[θ[x, y], y, y] - (Subscript[β, h] + V Subscript[β, c] [Theta][x, y] + (Subscript[β, h] θh[x, y] + V Subscript[β, c] θc[x, y]) == 0
```

with the boundary conditions ($\beta_h, \beta_c, V, \lambda_h, \lambda_c$ are constants)

$$\theta_w(0,y)=1, \theta_w(x,0)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(1,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,1)}{\partial y}=0$$

where \begin{eqnarray}
\theta_h(x,y) &=& \beta_h e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x,\\
\theta_c(x,y) &=& \beta_c e^{-\beta_c y} \int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{eqnarray}

It is also known that $\theta_h(0,y)=1$ and $\theta_c(x,0)=0$.

Trying with separation of variables:

Substituting $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ in $(1)$ and using the ansatz $\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$ we  obtain two linear third-order ODEs with constant coefficients for $F(x) := \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $G(y) := \int g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F &=& 0, \tag 2\\
V \lambda_c G''' - 2 V \lambda_c \beta_c G'' + \left( (\lambda_c \beta_c - 1) V \beta_c + \mu \right) G' + V \beta_c^2 G &=& 0,\tag 3
\end{eqnarray}
with some separation constant $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

The boundary conditions take the form:

**For G**: $G'(0)=0, G(0)=0$ and $\frac{G''(1)}{G'(1)}=\beta_c$

In order to get another homogeneous condition of $F$, we use $\theta_{h1}(x,y):=\theta_h (x,y)-1$. This does not change Eq. $(2)$ or $(3)$ but gives us another condition on $F$ i.e. $F'(0)=0$

**For F**: $\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h, F'(0)=0$

**Can anyone suggest a way forward in this problem ? I know I need to find the Eigenvalues $\mu$ and use the non-homogeneous b.c. and orthogonality to complete the solution, Krazug has already provided a method to find the $\mu$ values in an answer below. I need to understand how to use these with the $F$ equation to complete the $\theta_w$ solution**

---

**CONTEXT** The integro-differential equation from which the above problem arises is $D$:

I had a system of three PDEs
$$\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x}+\beta_h (\theta_h-\theta_w) = 0 \tag A$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c-\theta_w) = 0 \tag B$$

$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V\frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} - V\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} = 0 \tag C$$

On eliminating $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ from $C$ I reach
$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} +( -\beta_h - V \beta_c )\theta_w +\beta_h^2 e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y)  \mathrm{d}x + \beta_c^2 e^{-\beta_c y}\int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = 0 \tag D$$

The BCs are

$$\theta_w(0,y)=1, \theta_w(x,0)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(1,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,1)}{\partial y}=0$$
and $\theta_h(0,y)=1$, $\theta_c(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Do $\lambda_h$ and $\beta_h$ have values? And what are the other boundary conditions on $F$?

Comment: @KraZug $\lambda_h-\lambda_c$ and $\beta_h=\beta_c$. The other boundary conditions on $F$ could not be determined because the two other conditions left i.e $\theta_w(0,y)=1$ and $\theta_h(0,y)=1$ are non-homogeneous in nature.  I was hoping that once the eigenvalues are determined from the homogeneous $G$ equation, maybe they could be used to determine the function $F$. That is how I have seen PDE equations being solved in textbooks. But am I missing something here ? Can you suggest some alternative approach for this problem ?

Comment: Edit: $\lambda_h=\lambda_c$

Comment: Oh, I think I understand a bit more of what you are trying to do. I didn't realise you had an integro-differential equation. What values for mu do you currently get, because when I evaluate your code then I `FindRoot` errors regarding Accuracy/Precision, and it just returns the original start point without searching for a root.

Comment: @KraZug Appreciate your input, When i run the code, I too get accuracy warnings. Some values of `mu` I get are `1.18555e-8, -7, -20, -40,..`. This is what happens for me too, it returns to the original start point. And you are exactly right, this is an integro-differential equation. Basically, I have got stuck here. Even if I do find the eigen values $\mu$, I am at a loss here on how to build the final solution.

Comment: Yeah, those are not eigenvalues, it is just returning your input there. It is pretty unhelpful when it does that.

Comment: I've put a quick semi-answer to one of your questions. It by no means solves all your problems. If you knew another two BCs conditions on $F$ you could include them in this method, to solve for both sets simultaneously.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Can you help out with proceeding in this problem ? Would appreciate some inputs,

Comment: Can I suggest rewriting the question to remove older code, as well as writing the intero-differential equation explicitly.

Comment: @KraZug Added a context portion to the original question describing the PIDE and its origins.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a full answer to the question!

I have a package which helps solve eigenvalue BVPs by calculating the Evans function, an analytic function whose roots correspond to the eigenvalues. Some details are available at [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/solving-eigenvalue-bvp-with-an-interface/180502#180502) [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/finding-eigenvalues-for-a-boundary-value-problem/155728#155728) questions, or [this PDF](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf). Or search for `CompoundMatrixMethod` to see my previous answers here. It comes much better than the determinant method for finding roots accurately.

Install the package (also available on my [github page](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod)):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
    PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Load the package and setup the system:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]

eqn = {V λc G'''[x] - 2 V λc βc G''[x] + ((λc βc - 1) V βc + μ) G'[x] + V βc^2 G[x] == 0};
bcs = {G[0] == 0, G'[0] == 0, G''[1] == βc G'[1]};
sys = ToMatrixSystem[eqn, bcs, {G}, {x, 0, 1}, μ] /. βc ->
        0.921 /. λc -> 1.775*10^-4;
```

Now we can evaluate the Evans function at a given value of $\mu$ and $V$ with e.g. Evans[μ, sys /. V -> 1]. Roots of this function correspond to eigenvalues of that third order equation.

```
Plot[{Evans[μ, sys /. V -> 1], Evans[μ, sys /. V -> 2]}, {μ, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

You can see there is a periodic set of eigenvalues coming out for positive values of $\mu$, and it is worth noting that the eigenvalues for $V=2$ are exactly twice those for $V=1$.

```
FindRoot[Evans[μ, sys /. V -> 1], {μ, 2}]
{μ -> 1.97219}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. So I get the `mu` eigen-values for the $G$ equation using your method. Can these be not utilized to determine the other function with non-homogeneous condition ? I am just drawing on analogy here from standard PDE problem examples.

Comment: Or probably I should try to convert this problem into a homogeneous system using some form of transformation (something like $\bar{{\theta_h}}(x,y):=\theta_h(x,y)-1$). If I could do that, then both F and G could be solved simultaneously using your method. Subsequently,  what should be the next step in that scenario ?

Comment: I have found (in your code) that in your definition of  `sys`, you have used `eqns` instead of `eqn` which defines the $G$ equation. When I plot the same system with same parameters the eigenvalue plots are different. I have added the plot as an addendum to my original question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was my mistake, I had a lingering definition and didn't check anything before posting last night. I'm not a PDE expert, so I'm not sure what steps you'll need to make next, but yes, you can solve the two eigenvalue BVPs simultaneously if they are homogeneous.

Comment: Appreciate it @KraZug

Comment: Worth noting that the eigenvalues you see for $V=2$ are exactly twice those for $V=1$.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I am  sure that any solution I develop for this problem will have  your method as a an intermediate step. Said that, I have managed to make a transformation which gives me another homogeneous condition in $F$ (made these edits in the original question), so I am left with just one non-homogeneous condition in $F$, which I now strongly believe will be used to determine the unknown coefficients. It is exactly this I am trying to figure out now.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty award, even though it isn't a complete answer, I hope that my method is at least helpful for finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes that is exactly why I awarded the bounty to you. Although I am using your method with the `findAllRoots` function you suggested in an answer elsewhere. I am finding it to correctly detect all the intersection points.

Comment: Yeah, `findAllRoots` is very useful for finding the roots in a smooth function.