# Numerical eigenvalues of the problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I have this equations with condition `0 <= x <= 1`:

```
eqns = {((2 - x) y''[x])'' + λ y''[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[1] == 0}
```

So I need to find the first 4 eigenvalues here. I tried to use `NDEigenvalues` and get this error `NDEigenvalues::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.`
How can I avoid it? I got answer when used `z[x] = y''[x]`: `{1.72307*10^-13, -15.0124, -58.1943, -130.156}`, but I'm not sure that I'm right.

Comment: This piece of code `((2 - x) y''[x])''` is not going to work.

Comment: I can replace it with `[D[(2 - x) y''[x], x], x]` or `-2 y'''[x] + (2 - x) y''''[x]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although there are a number of related ways to solve this problem, the cleanest appears be replacing `y''[x]` by `z[x]` to obtain

```
spp = DSolveValue[{D[(2 - x) z[x], {x, 2}] + λ z[x] == 0}, z[x], x]
(* (Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ] BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ]] C[1])/(2 - x) 
 - (Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ] BesselK[1, 2 Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ]] C[2])/(2 - x) *)
```

Then, `Integrate` to obtain `y'[x]` and `y[x]` in turn.

```
sp = Integrate[spp, x] + C[3]
(* C[1] - BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ]] C[1] 
        - BesselK[0, 2 Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ]] C[2] + C[3] *)
s = Simplify@Integrate[sp, x] + C[4]
(* (Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ] BesselK[1, 2 Sqrt[(-2 + x) λ]] C[2])/λ + x (C[1] + C[3]) + C[4] 
   - (-2 + x) C[1] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, (-2 + x) λ] *)
```

and compute the determinant of the boundary conditions.

```
CoefficientArrays[{spp /. x -> 1, sp /. x -> 0, s /. x -> 0, s /. x -> 1}, 
    {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}] // Normal // Last;
disp = Det[%] // FullSimplify
(* 1/2 π Sqrt[λ] (-BesselY[1, 2 Sqrt[λ]] (Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, -2 λ] 
   - 2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -2 λ]) 
   + (Sqrt[λ] BesselY[0, 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[λ]] - Sqrt[2] BesselY[1, 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[λ]]) 
   Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -λ]) *)
```

Plotting this function shows its zeroes.

```
Plot[Chop@disp, {λ, -5, 250}, AxesLabel -> {λ, d}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

(`disp` becomes exponentially large at negative `λ`.)  The first four zeroes are `0` and

```
{FindRoot[disp, {λ, 30}], FindRoot[disp, {λ, 90}], FindRoot[disp, {λ, 170}]} 
    // Flatten // Chop // Values
(* {29.4788, 87.0186, 173.309} *)
```

**Addendum**

Even more compact is

```
disp = FullSimplify@Det[Normal@Last@CoefficientArrays[
    DSolveValue[{D[(2 - x) y''[x], {x, 2}] + λ y''[x] == 0}, 
    {y[0], y[1], y'[0], y''[1]}, x], {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}]];
Table[FindRoot[disp, {λ, λ0}], {λ0, {30, 90, 170}}] // Flatten // Values
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm really glad to see this full answer.

Comment: I was impeded by the word "eigenvalues".

Answer (score 4):

The answer by bbgodfrey is excellent for this particularly problem, because it can be solved directly by DSolve.

Having said that, I have a package which helps solve eigenvalue BVPs by calculating the Evans function, an analytic function whose roots correspond to the eigenvalues. Some details are available at [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/solving-eigenvalue-bvp-with-an-interface/180502#180502) [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/finding-eigenvalues-for-a-boundary-value-problem/155728#155728) questions, or [this PDF](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf). Or search for `CompoundMatrixMethod` to see my previous answers here.

Install the package (also available on my [github page](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod)):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
    PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Load the package and setup the system:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
sys = ToMatrixSystem[D[(2 - x) y''[x], x, x] + λ y''[x] == 0, 
         {y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[1] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, λ]
```

Now we can evaluate the Evans function at a given value of $\lambda$ with e.g. Evans[1, sys]. Roots of this function correspond to eigenvalues of the original equation:

```
Plot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, 0, 250}]
```

We can see that this corresponds to the eigenvalues shown in bbgodfrey's answer, although without the $\lambda = 0$ root, which isn't a real eigenvalue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KraZug's entirely numerical solution reminded me of another approach, employing a variation on an example described in the `NDSolve` documentation, [Boundary Value Problems with Parameters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691).  However, the documented approach, which entails treating the parameter as a variable to be computed, has only one solution for the parameter, and the example equation has an adequate number of boundary conditions.  Here, the parameter `λ` can assume an infinite number of values, and treating it as a variable requires an additional boundary condition.  Not coincidentally, however, the normalization of the eigenfunctins is arbitrary, and an additional boundary condition for `y` merely specifies the normalization, which subsequently can be changed (as done below with the variable `norm`), if desired.  And, different values for `λ` can be sought by providing different initial guesses for it.  With this as preface,

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[(2 - x) y''[x], {x, 2}] + λ[x] y''[x] == 0, λ'[x] == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1, y''[1] == 0}, {y[x], λ[0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    {λ0}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {λ[0] == λ0}}];
```

The extra boundary condition is `y''[0] == 1`.  I also tried `y'[1] == 1`, but it works much less well, because the "Shooting" `Method` then must deal with three unknowns instead of two.  The first ten eigenvalues and their associated eigenfunctions then are obtained by

```
Transpose@Table[s[n], {n, {30, 90, 170, 300, 450, 600, 770, 1050, 1300, 1600}}];
norm = 1/Sqrt@NIntegrate[First[%]^2, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[norm First[%%]], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {y, x},
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {1, .5}]]
Last[%%%]
```

[image]

```
{29.4788, 87.0186, 173.309, 288.359, 432.171, 604.744, 806.079, 1036.18, 1295.04, 1582.66}
```

Comment: That is nice! Gets you the eigenfunctions immediately too, which my package doesn't do without some work.