# Eigenvalue problem with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, eigenvalues, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the following system of linear ODEs. It is an eigenvalue problem.

```
\[Chi] = 1;
m = 1.495;
\[Theta] = -\[Chi]^(-1/m)*(-1 + \[Chi]^(1/m));
n = Log[Abs[\[Chi]]];

l = 2;
k = 0;
a = Sqrt[(l^2 + k^2)];

Pr = 0.1;
Ta = 10^5;
\[Phi] = Pi/4;
Ra = 2*10^(05);

sol1 = NDSolve[{(a^2 Pr + \[Sigma]) Subscript[Z, 0][z] + (
     m Pr \[Theta] Subscript[Z, 1][z])/(1 + z \[Theta]) == 
    Pr (Sqrt[
        Ta] ((I l Cos[\[Phi]] + (m \[Theta] Sin[\[Phi]])/(
             1 + z \[Theta])) Subscript[W, 0][z] + 
          Sin[\[Phi]] Subscript[W, 1][z]) + 
       Derivative[1][Subscript[Z, 1]][z]), 
   Pr (((3 (-2 + m) m \[Theta]^4 + (a + a z \[Theta])^4) Subscript[W, 
         0][z])/(1 + z \[Theta])^4 + (
       m \[Theta] ((-4 + m) \[Theta] Subscript[W, 2][z] + 
          2 (1 + z \[Theta]) Subscript[W, 3][z]))/(1 + z \[Theta])^2 +
        Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 3]][z]) == 
    a^2 Pr Ra Subscript[S, 0][z] + (
     2 a^2 m^2 Pr \[Theta]^2 Subscript[W, 0][z])/(
     3 (1 + z \[Theta])^2) + (
     3 (-2 + m) m Pr \[Theta]^3 Subscript[W, 1][z])/(1 + 
       z \[Theta])^3 + (2 a^2 m Pr \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][z])/(
     1 + z \[Theta]) + 
     2 a^2 Pr Subscript[W, 2][
       z] + \[Sigma] ((-a^2 - (
           m \[Theta]^2)/(1 + z \[Theta])^2) Subscript[W, 0][z] + (
        m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][z])/(1 + z \[Theta]) + 
        Subscript[W, 2][z]) + 
     Pr Sqrt[Ta] (I Cos[\[Phi]] ((k m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 0][z])/(
           1 + z \[Theta]) + l Subscript[Z, 0][z]) + 
        Sin[\[Phi]] Subscript[Z, 1][z]), (a^2 (1 + 
          z \[Theta])^-m + \[Sigma]) Subscript[S, 0][
      z] == (1 + z \[Theta])^(-1 - 
      m) (\[Theta] Subscript[S, 1][z] + (1 + z \[Theta])^
        m Subscript[W, 0][z] + (1 + z \[Theta]) Derivative[1][
         Subscript[S, 1]][z]), 
   Subscript[W, 1][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 0]][z], 
   Subscript[W, 2][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 1]][z], 
   Subscript[W, 3][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 2]][z], 
   Subscript[S, 1][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[S, 0]][z], 
   Subscript[Z, 1][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[Z, 0]][z], 
   Subscript[S, 0][0] == 0, Subscript[S, 0][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 0][0] == 0, Subscript[W, 0][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[Z, 1][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 2][0] + 
     m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][0]/(1 + 0 \[Theta]) == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 2][1] + 
     m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][1]/(1 + \[Theta]) == 0}, {Subscript[W,
    0], Subscript[Z, 0], Subscript[S, 0], \[Sigma]}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Additional condition that can be used is

```
Subscript[Z, 0][0]==1
```

I want to solve for the unknown functions and sigma. But right now I am unable to do it. I tried to follow the approach given in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html but it didn't work for me. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html)?

Comment: @user21 I have tried it but since sigma in the above equation is unknown, I am not sure how to place the equations in the NDEigensystem function.

Comment: Your code contains `Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 1, Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 0`, one of which is incorrect.  What are the correct boundary conditions?  Also, you need a ninth boundary condition to solve this problem, because the eigenvalue also is an unknown.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you for pointing it out. Indeed, those conditions are incorrect. I have made changes to those boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional condition. However, the code now contains `Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 0`, which is a duplicate. Another boundary condition is needed to give a total of nine.  Eight is sufficient only if all boundary conditions are homogeneous.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I made a mistake there too. Now I have corrected it. My boundary conditions are homogeneous.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question probably can be solved with `NDSolve`, it is more convenient to solve it with `DSolve`.  To begin, name the ODEs and boundary conditions given in the question as `eqs` with all quantities `Rationalize`d.  Then solve the ODEs with the boundary conditions at `z = 0`.  (Including all boundary conditions at once produces ungainly results.)

```
v = Variables[Subtract @@@ eqs[[;; 8]]][[2 ;; 9]]
dsol = DSolve[Join[eqs[[;; 8]], eqs[[{9, 11, 13, 15}]]], v, z] // Flatten
```

With a `LeafCount` of `9320`, `dsol` is too large to reproduce here.  It consists of four equations involving `RootSum`s and four constants of integration.

```
c = Cases[dsol, C[_], Infinity] // Union
(* {C[2], C[4], C[6], C[7]} *)
```

Now, apply the four boundary conditions at `z = 1` and express the result as a matrix.

```
eqs[[10 ;; 16 ;; 2]] /. (dsol /. z -> 1);
CoefficientArrays[%, c] // Last;
disp = Det[%];
```

The roots of `disp == 0` are the desired eigenvalues, the first four of which are

```
FindRoot[disp, {σ, -.1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Chop
(* {σ -> -0.0873219119392251168866661775144} *)
```

and similarly

```
(* {σ -> -1.27987460528269767318780120707} *)
(* {σ -> -68.8450688277416266702085885341} *)
(* {σ -> -81.1196686184117486120744862461} *)
```

A plot of negative `σ` is given by

```
Show[
    Plot[Chop[disp], {σ, -260, -67}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {σ, "disp"}, 
        LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> {{-260, 0}, Automatic},
    Plot[Re[disp], {σ, -2, 1/4}, ImageSize -> Large] ]
```

[image]

Comment: it is an interesting approach to solving this problem. Thank you so much. I am going to use it. Could you please also write how you entered the equations? Also, I am posting my solution obtained with NDSolve. Please comment on that.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA, In answer to your question about the equations I used, I used `eqs = { ... }`, where `{ ... }` is the first set of curly brackets in `NDSolve` in the question and all the code it contains.  I also set `m = 1495/1000` and `Pr = 1/10` in the constants to obtain a more accurate answer.

Comment: @bbgodgrey Thank you. I was able to do that by carefully going through your code. How can we approach the problem when both Ra and Sigma are unknown parameters? It is true that the code I presented fails at many points.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA Just as SPPearce noted in response to a similar question, my approach can provide `σ` as a function of `Ra`.  To determine values for both of then requires an additional relation between the two quantities.  Is one available?

Comment: The additional relation would be $a(Ra)=0$, where $\sigma=a+i b$. Can that be used?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to bbgodfrey's typically excellent analytical solution, that will work for equations that can't be solved by `DSolve`.

I happen to have written a package to solve eigenvalue equations of this type, using the Evans function.

The Evans function is an analytic function whose roots correspond to the eigenvalues. Some details are available at [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/solving-eigenvalue-bvp-with-an-interface/180502#180502) [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/finding-eigenvalues-for-a-boundary-value-problem/155728#155728) questions, [my github page](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod) and [this PDF](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Exl/FYB-background.pdf), or search for `CompoundMatrixMethod` to see my previous answers here.

Install the package (also available on my [github page](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod)):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
    PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Load the package:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
```

Parameters (without setting Ra, and rationalising):

```
χ = 1;
m = Rationalize[1.495];
θ = -χ^(-1/m)*(-1 + χ^(1/m));
n = Log[Abs[χ]];

l = 2;
k = 0;
a = Sqrt[(l^2 + k^2)];

Pr = 1/10;
Ta = 10^5;
ϕ = Pi/4;
```

And your equations:

```
eqs = {(a^2 Pr + σ) Z0[z] + (m Pr θ Z1[z])/(1 + z θ) == 
    Pr (Sqrt[Ta] ((I l Cos[ϕ] + (m θ Sin[ϕ])/(1 + z θ)) W0[z] + Sin[ϕ] W1[z]) + Z1'[z]), 
   Pr (((3 (-2 + m) m θ^4 + (a + a z θ)^4) W0[z])/(1 + z θ)^4 + (m θ ((-4 + m) θ W2[z] +  2 (1 + z θ) W3[z]))/(1 + z θ)^2 + W3'[z]) == a^2 Pr Ra S0[z] + (2 a^2 m^2 Pr θ^2 W0[z])/(3 (1 + z θ)^2) + (3 (-2 + m) m Pr θ^3 W1[z])/(1 + z θ)^3 + (2 a^2 m Pr θ W1[z])/(1 + z θ) + 
     2 a^2 Pr W2[z] + σ ((-a^2 - (m θ^2)/(1 + z θ)^2) W0[z] + (m θ W1[z])/(1 + z θ) + W2[z]) + 
     Pr Sqrt[Ta] (I Cos[ϕ] ((k m θ W0[z])/(1 + z θ) + l Z0[z]) + 
        Sin[ϕ] Z1[z]), (a^2 (1 + z θ)^-m + σ) S0[z] == (1 + z θ)^(-1 - m) (θ S1[z] + (1 + z θ)^m W0[z] + (1 + z θ) S1'[z]), W1[z] == W0'[z], 
   W2[z] == W1'[z], W3[z] == W2'[z], S1[z] == S0'[z], Z1[z] == Z0'[z],
    S0[0] == 0, S0[1] == 0, W0[0] == 0, W0[1] == 0, Z1[0] == 0, 
   Z1[1] == 0, W2[0] + m θ W1[0]/(1 + 0 θ) == 0, 
   W2[1] + m θ W1[1]/(1 + θ) == 0};
```

We use the function `ToMatrixSystem` to convert this system into a matrix form

```
sys[Ra_] = ToMatrixSystem[eqs[[;; 8]],eqs[[9 ;; 16]], {S0, S1, W0, W1, W2, W3, Z0, Z1}, {z, 0, 1}, σ];
```

Now we can evaluate the Evans function for a given value of $\sigma$ , say $\sigma = 1$ and $Ra = 200000$.

```
Evans[1, sys[200000]]
(* 0.000545625 + 0. I *)
```

This is not zero, so $\sigma=1$ is not an eigenvalue of the system. So we can use `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[Evans[σ, sys[200000]], {σ, 1}]
{σ -> -1.27987 - 3.69498*10^-17 I}
```

Agreeing with bbgodfrey's solution.

If we plot the Evans function, we can see that it has further negative roots, again copying the analytical solution:

```
Plot[Evans[σ, sys[200000]], {σ, -250, 0}]
```

[image]

To find a value of $Ra$ where an eigenvalue crosses the y-axis is a bit tricky, as there are multiple eigenvalues, so you'll need to be very careful. However, one method is to ensure you start the FindRoot close to the previous root. I have some examples of this in the notebook on my github.

Some quick playing around suggests there is an eigenvalue that crosses between $8000<=Ra=10000$:

```
FindRoot[Evans[σ, sys[8000]], {σ, 10 I}]
FindRoot[Evans[σ, sys[10000]], {σ, 10 I}]

(* {σ -> -0.324265 + 14.6518 I} *)

(* {σ -> 0.523407 + 14.1909 I} *)
```

So we will try and see where this one crosses.

Make a temporary function:

```
Clear[rootfn]
rootfn[Ra_?NumericQ] := σ /. 
  FindRoot[Evans[σ, sys[Ra]], {σ, 15 I}]
```

And then find where the real part of this disappears:

```
FindRoot[Re[rootfn[Ra]], {Ra, 9000}]
(* {Ra -> 8758.34} *)
```

Comment: Great approach (+1).

Comment: @SPPearce thank you so much for presenting your method here. I will definitely going to use it. Does it help when there are two unknown parameters?

Comment: What is your extra condition/equation to include another parameter? The matrix system can depend on another parameter, which you can then vary to see how the eigenvalues change for instance.

Comment: @SPPearce the extra condition that can be used is $a(Ra)=0$, where $\sigma=a+ib$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that condition. $Re(\sigma)*R_a = 0$?

Comment: @SPPearce Oh I am sorry. Let me write that in words, then it will be more clear. It means I need that $\sigma$ and $Ra$ for which the real part of $\sigma$, that is, $\Re{(\sigma)}$ is zero. What you have written is also correct, provided it is a multiplication.

Comment: Ok, you want to find a value of $Ra$ for which $\sigma$ becomes purely imaginary?

Comment: I have found one such value of $Ra$. But as there are a number of eigenvalues, you'll need to be careful to follow particular roots and there could easily be a smaller value that crosses. Please also check the equations, I have rewritten them without using `Subscript`. Also you don't need to rewrite them into a set of 1st order ODEs like Matlab requires (my package does that in `ToMatrixSystem`), you could just keep your actual structure.

Comment: @SPPearce This works nicely for me. Thank you so much for these solutions. Also, the Package works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used NDSolve to obtain the solution. Thanks to @bbgodfrey for pointing out the incorrect boundary conditions.

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{(a^2 Pr + I \[Sigma][z]) Subscript[Z, 0][z] + (
     m Pr \[Theta] Subscript[Z, 1][z])/(1 + z \[Theta]) == 
    Pr (Sqrt[
        Ta] ((I l Cos[\[Phi]] + (m \[Theta] Sin[\[Phi]])/(
             1 + z \[Theta])) Subscript[W, 0][z] + 
          Sin[\[Phi]] Subscript[W, 1][z]) + 
       Derivative[1][Subscript[Z, 1]][z]), 
   Pr (((3 (-2 + m) m \[Theta]^4 + (a + a z \[Theta])^4) Subscript[W, 
         0][z])/(1 + z \[Theta])^4 + (
       m \[Theta] ((-4 + m) \[Theta] Subscript[W, 2][z] + 
          2 (1 + z \[Theta]) Subscript[W, 3][z]))/(1 + z \[Theta])^2 +
        Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 3]][z]) == 
    a^2 Pr Ra[z] Subscript[S, 0][z] + (
     2 a^2 m^2 Pr \[Theta]^2 Subscript[W, 0][z])/(
     3 (1 + z \[Theta])^2) + (
     3 (-2 + m) m Pr \[Theta]^3 Subscript[W, 1][z])/(1 + 
       z \[Theta])^3 + (2 a^2 m Pr \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][z])/(
     1 + z \[Theta]) + 2 a^2 Pr Subscript[W, 2][z] + 
     I \[Sigma][
       z] ((-a^2 - (m \[Theta]^2)/(1 + z \[Theta])^2) Subscript[W, 0][
          z] + (m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][z])/(1 + z \[Theta]) + 
        Subscript[W, 2][z]) + 
     Pr Sqrt[Ta] (I Cos[\[Phi]] ((k m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 0][z])/(
           1 + z \[Theta]) + l Subscript[Z, 0][z]) + 
        Sin[\[Phi]] Subscript[Z, 1][z]), (a^2 (1 + z \[Theta])^-m + 
       I \[Sigma][z]) Subscript[S, 0][z] == (1 + z \[Theta])^(-1 - 
      m) (\[Theta] Subscript[S, 1][z] + (1 + z \[Theta])^
        m Subscript[W, 0][z] + (1 + z \[Theta]) Derivative[1][
         Subscript[S, 1]][z]), 
   Subscript[W, 1][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 0]][z], 
   Subscript[W, 2][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 1]][z], 
   Subscript[W, 3][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[W, 2]][z], 
   Subscript[S, 1][z] == Derivative[1][Subscript[S, 0]][z], 
   Subscript[Z, 1][z] == 
    Derivative[1][Subscript[Z, 0]][z], \[Sigma]'[z] == 0, Ra'[z] == 0,
    Subscript[S, 0][0] == 0, Subscript[S, 0][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 0][0] == 0, Subscript[W, 0][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[Z, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[Z, 1][1] == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 2][0] + 
     m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][0]/(1 + 0 \[Theta]) == 0, 
   Subscript[W, 2][1] + 
     m \[Theta] Subscript[W, 1][1]/(1 + \[Theta]) == 0, 
   Subscript[Z, 0][0] == 1, Subscript[Z, 0][1] == 10}, {Subscript[W, 
   0], Subscript[Z, 0], Subscript[S, 0], \[Sigma], Ra}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}]
```

Here, you will see that I have kept Ra as an unknown parameter in addition to sigma. The eigenvalue and Ra can be extracted as

```
\[Sigma][0]/.sol1
Ra[0]/.sol1
```

The problem that I see here, is the extra conditions required to obtain a solution. These extra conditions might not be known beforehand.
Other problem is if the extra conditions are homogeneous then you would not get the true eigenvalues.
I have not checked the solution using another method.

Comment: Your code fails with a FindRoot error, and the resulting answers are incorrect.  You might try restoring ``Ra` as a constant and deleting one of the extra boundary conditions.

Comment: Your code can be made to work by converting `Ra` back to a constant, removing `Ra'[z] == 0`  and `Subscript[Z, 0][1] == 10`, and returning `I σ[z]` to `σ[z]` (for consistency with the question).  It also helps to add `"StartingInitialConditions" -> σ[0] == -68845/1000` (or whatever initial guess you wish).  This method, which is described in the documentation, has the advantage of giving the eigenfunction along with the eigenvalue, but it is slow and requires a reasonable initial guess.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for detailed analysis. I've noted the suggestions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey $Ra$ and $\sigma$ should be such that $\Re(\sigma)=0$ for a given $Ra$. That is, I need that $Ra$ for which $\Re(\sigma)=0$. Can we work with that?

Comment: Having read your discussion with SPPearce, I am confident that requiring `Re[σ] = 0`  will not determine `Ra`.  (I presume you mean `Re[σ] = 0`, where `σ` is defined as in your answer just above, which would be the same as `Im[σ] = 0`, where `σ` is defined as in your question.)

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much for solving my issues. The solutions that you gave are so helpful. In the above case, I'll just vary Ra such that $\Re(\sigma)=0$ and $\Im(\sigma)\neq0$, that will be one way.

Comment: Do you expect `Ra` determined in this way to be real or complex?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Ra should be real.

Comment: There may be multiple values of Ra for which an eigenvalue becomes positive. I have found one such value below. An issue is finding where the eigenvalues that don't lie upon the negative real axis are, as the negative real ones seem to attract the FindRoot solution strongly. At Ra=200000 there is one at $\sigma = 8.049 + 11.36 I$. This moves around the complex plane as Ra is varied.

Comment: @SPPearce It is a good observation. But I didn't understand your first sentence. It seems like for a given $Ra$ there are eigenvalues with both negative and positive real parts. $\sigma=8.049-11.36i$ is also an eigenvalue for $Ra=200000$. The physics requires that when $Re(\sigma)=0$ occurs, that $Ra$ is unique. But I would have to play around bit. Thank you.