# Are compound matrices implemented in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, linear-algebra

Compound matrices are  matrices whose entries are all the minors of a given size of another matrix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_matrix

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James-Muldowney-2/publication/38372479_Compound_matrices_and_ordinary_differential_equations/links/58b1b9a8aca2725b5416ed5f/Compound-matrices-and-ordinary-differential-equations.pdf

They are probably not too hard to write by the user, but maybe I am lucky and they are already  implemented in mathematica ?  Thanks :)

Comment: `Minors` does this for square matrices. It was recently noticed that we did not extend to rectangular, so we added support for that to a future release.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please correct me, but at least in versions 12.0.0 and 13.0.0, ```Minors``` seems to give sensible results for rectangular matrices as well?

Comment: @Hausdorff Not that I can see: `In[209]:= Minors[Array[a, {2, 3}]]

During evaluation of In[209]:= Minors::matsq: Argument {{a[1,1],a[1,2],a[1,3]},{a[2,1],a[2,2],a[2,3]}} at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix.

Out[209]= Minors[{{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], 
   a[2, 3]}}]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It does do it if you specify the order of the minor matrix, e.g. ```Minors[Array[a, {2, 3}], 2]```

Comment: @DanielLichtblau And it seems you would need to specify the order to make the minor matrix well-defined in the rectangular case. In your example you could image dropping either a column and row each time (leading to 1×1 "determinants"), or only a column (leading to 2×2 determinants). I don't see which would be the natural extension of the square case. Plus, for the compound matrix, you have to to specify the minor order anyways.

Comment: Thanks @Hausdorff, I did not think to check that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau hausdorff Brilliant, these comments are well worth putting as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that they are built-in, but they are easy enough to implement:

```
CompoundMatrix[A_?MatrixQ, k_Integer] := Module[{m, n, p, q, i, j},
   {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
   p = Subsets[Range[1, m], {k}];
   q = Subsets[Range[1, n], {k}];
   Table[Det[A[[i, j]]], {i, p}, {j, q}]
   ];
```

Using the elementary example from the linked *Wikipedia* article:

```
A = Partition[Range[1, 12], 4];
CompoundMatrix[A, 2]
```

> {{-4, -8, -12, -4, -8, -4}, {-8, -16, -24, -8, -16, -8}, {-4, -8, -12, -4, -8, -4}}

Comment: The variables ```i```, ```j``` used for ```Table``` should also be made local in ```Module``` to avoid bugs, such as for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262082/73380)

Comment: @Hausdorff The variables `i` and `j` are scoped by `Table` itself. This should not be the reason for any bugs.

Comment: @Hausdorff The documentation of `Table` says: "`Table` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables."

Comment: But the scoping includes the first argument of ```Table```. After setting ```f = i```, compare for example ```Table[f, {i, 1, 3}]``` and ```Module[{i}, Table[f, {i, 1, 3}]]```. In the latter, ```Module``` ensures that ```i``` is different from any other ```i``` in definitions outside the ```Module```.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant here. After all, all other variables are scoped either by the pattern or by ˋModuleˋ.

Comment: It is relevant if you for example pass a matrix like ```A = {{i, j}, {j, i}}``` into ```CompoundMatrix```. In this case, the ```i``` and ```j``` of the matrix elements will also be replaced with the iterator values

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. This never occured to me. Thanks for the lesson! =)

Comment: No worries, this is also the first time I have stumbled over this :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for answering a year-old question with a self-plug, I've moved out of the applied mathematics field and no longer keep an eye on this site.

I have a package that implements the method of compound matrices for solving eigenvalue boundary value problems by calculating the Evans function, an analytic function whose roots correspond to the eigenvalues. Some details are available at [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/solving-eigenvalue-bvp-with-an-interface/180502#180502) [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/finding-eigenvalues-for-a-boundary-value-problem/155728#155728) questions, or [this PDF](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Exl/FYB-background.pdf). Or search for `CompoundMatrixMethod` on this site to see my other answers here.